# maximum number of port can open in Socket connection in j2me

Tags: sockets, java-me, port, connection

What is maximum number ports can open at a same time using socket connection in J2me mobile devices for a IM application.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can open 26 ports at a time in J2ME Mobile.

Comment: you should also say which device you are using.